# How to escape single quote from parsing inside command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have to start the command at the bottom as a specific user in a script. the parameter $vmargs needs to be in single quotes ('$vmargs'). im stuck here because its always parsed.
the vmargs parameter has some java options within.

```
 su synesty -c "screen -dmS appscreen ./eclipse -vmargs 
                -DAPP_ENV=$automatey_note  $vmargs"
```

Hope anyone can help.

Update: Sorry I saw my question was not clear. The parameter have to be solved.

```
 '-DencryptorCredentials=currentPass|oldPass|1 -Xms512m -Xmx2048m 
 -DLOGGING_HOME=configuration/ -Djava.io.tmpdir=/tmp -Dorg.osgi.service.http.port=8081
 -Declipse.ignoreApp=true -Dosgi.noShutdown=true -Xdebug         
 -Xnoagent
 -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n 
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -DapplyDbMigrations=true -XX:MaxPermSize=128m     
 -XX:-HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError '
```

Thats the stuff and I need the single quotes, otherwise shell will not recognize it as parameters

Comment: Can you clarify whether you want to pass `$vmargs` literally (i.e. not expanded) or whether you just want to enclose the expanded value in single quotes (i.e. `'here is the java code'`)?

Comment: yeah i want to enclose the expanded value in single quotes, sorry question was not really well defined

Answer (score 1):

Just put single quotes around `$vmargs`. It will still be expanded because the whole thing is in double-quotes.

```
su synesty -c "screen -dmS appscreen ./eclipse -vmargs -DAPP_ENV=$automatey_note '$vmargs'"
```

Comment: i've updated my question. vmargs have to be solved with single quotes

Comment: I have got single quotes around `vmargs` in my answer. Have you tried it?

Comment: at the top i described, what vmargs is. i have to expand it with single quotes '-Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=4000,server=y,suspend=n 
 -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true ' and so on

Comment: it will be expanded and the whole thing will be surrounded by single quotes. Have you tried it?

Comment: yeah i tried it, but it still doesnt work. i get this ' \ ' ' parameters.... ' \ ' '

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pass `$vmargs` to `su synesty` unchanged, "escape" the dollar which will preserve the string as-is:-

`su synesty -c "screen -dmS appscreen ./eclipse -vmargs -DAPP_ENV=$automatey_note \$vmargs"`